# How do you test a SQL statements across multiple Database types?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sugarcrm

Does anyone know of a quick and easy test to see if a query is properly formatted for both MySQL & MSSQL. Perhaps other database types as well, such as SQL Server? I only have access to MySQL at this time.

Info: I'm working on an Open Source project called JJWDesign Google Maps for SugarCRM. Some of the queries use the SugarCRM classes; others I have to write custom. For example, some are special distance calculations against the geocode information stored in the tables.

http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/jjwgooglemaps/

Comment: www.sqlfiddle.com is half decent.  But, realistically, you may find that a one-code-fits-all approach compromises capability and performance.  The more complex approach, of an abstraction layer to implement different code on different sql platforms, may yield better long terms results.

Comment: SugarCRM does have an abstraction layer, but I hesitate to trust it. DBManager.php (helper/manager).

Comment: I just started messing with sqlfiddle.com. This will definitely help! Thanks Dems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More importantly, while there is an accepted syntax, each flavour of database has it's own specific functions, features and things you can do.

The best you can do is to make do with the most basic of features. Oracle has different functions for datetime compared to mysql compared to db2. While I would love to assist in a 'free as in beer' project, you really will need to check each function to see if it is the same across all major vendors. General functions most often are, so `abs()` will be fairly consistent, but others simply won't.

Comment: I am using some SQL functions such as SQRT() and COS(). Do you think those would present a problem?

Comment: @jjwdesign It really depends on the function. Check your functions to see if they are accepted in the same format across all the databases you expect to be used in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about a SQL parser so by definition it either isn't going to be quick and easy or it will do only the simplest checking.

Each RDBMS has its own flavour of SQL too so you'd really be limited to testing whether it was ANSI SQL.